# Blade Tool Stuck on Grid in Final Cut

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, timecode, music

In final cut pro x on catalina I have an audio clip and video clip on top of each other in the project.

I am attempting to cut both at a specific point, corresponding to a transition in the song on the audio track, with the Blade tool. However, final cut is snapping my blade to the time grid and only allows me to cut these clips in one second increments.

How can I use the blade to cut where ever I want regardless of the time grid?

PS. if anyone knows how to set a BPM grid in FCPX that'd be swell. I tried BeatMark 2 but it doesn't run on my system (probably Catalina related).

Answer (score 2):

You can only cut in-between frames of your video clips.

Videos have generally frame rates per second of 24 or 25, maybe 30. Sound files have typically a sample rate per second of 48000. So you could say you can cut a video e.g. 25 times per second and a sound file 48000 times.

I usually cut to the nearest frame to the beat of the music. IMHO nobody can tell the difference of one or the other frame with a beat in between.
Try both versions and choose what feels the best.

FCPX is not sound editor like logic pro or pro tools. BPM don't apply for FCPX, it's the frame rate of the timeline and clips used what matters more.

Comment: I'm not able to cut in between frame / audio samples, this is the problem. I am only able to make cuts at one second. If I could cut between frames and audio samples then I'd be good.

Comment: With Command - Plus and Command - Minus you can zoom in and out.